# Background of button dont align with shadow in vertical menu

Tags: css, button, menu

I'm doing a project to see how well elders handle flat- vs skeuomorphic design. To do this I want to make the menu 3D and realistic. I found a pre made button that suited my purpose but when i try to make it vertical the shadow fills up the whole parent but the background doesn't.. This is the code im using for the horizontal button: http://jsfiddle.net/ahu8n91o/

HTML:

```
<a class="button">
    <span>TEXT FOR BUTTON</span>
</a>
<a class="button">
    <span>BUTTON 2</span>
</a>
<a class="button">
    <span>ANOTHER BUTTON</span>
</a>
<a class="button">
    <span>LAST BUTTON</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;

    width: auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 
        0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1), /* gradient effects */
        0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
        0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
        0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
        0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
        0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
        0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128,128,128,1); /* shadow */

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
} 

.button span {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;

    background-image: 
        /* gloss gradient */
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left bottom, 
            left top, 
            color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), 
            color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.3)), 
            color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2))),

        /* dark outside gradient */
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left top, 
            right top, 
            color-stop(0%,rgba(210,210,210,0.3)), 
            color-stop(20%,rgba(210,210,210,0)), 
            color-stop(80%,rgba(210,210,210,0)), 
            color-stop(100%,rgba(210,210,210,0.3))),

        /* light inner gradient */
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left top, 
            right top, 
            color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), 
            color-stop(20%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), 
            color-stop(80%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), 
            color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));        

        -webkit-box-shadow:
            0px -1px #fff, /* top highlight */
            0px 1px 1px #FFFFFF; /* bottom edge */

    -webkit-background-size: 100%, 100%, 100%, 4px 4px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out;

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;

    color: #3A474D;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2em;

    text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #262F33;
}

.button span:hover {
    color: #AEBF3B;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px #97A63A;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover span{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 1px); /* depth of button press */
}
.button:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
        0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1),
        0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
        0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
        0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
        0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
        0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
        0px 10px 2px 0px rgba(128,128,128,.6); /* shadow */
}
.button:active span{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px); /* depth of button press */
}
```

But when i try to make it vertical it mess up like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ahu8n91o/1/

HTML:

```
<link  href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,500,600,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

<link  href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:regular,bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

<div class="container">

    <a class="button">
        <span>TEXT FOR BUTTON</span>
    </a>
    <a class="button">
        <span>BUTTON 2</span>
    </a>
    <a class="button">
        <span>ANOTHER BUTTON</span>
    </a>
    <a class="button">
        <span>LAST BUTTON</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.button {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;

    width: auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 
        0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1), /* gradient effects */
        0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
        0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
        0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
        0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
        0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
        0px 14px 6px -1px rgba(128,128,128,1); /* shadow */

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
} 

.button span {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;

    background-image: 
        /* gloss gradient */
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left bottom, 
            left top, 
            color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), 
            color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.3)), 
            color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2))),

        /* dark outside gradient */
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left top, 
            right top, 
            color-stop(0%,rgba(210,210,210,0.3)), 
            color-stop(20%,rgba(210,210,210,0)), 
            color-stop(80%,rgba(210,210,210,0)), 
            color-stop(100%,rgba(210,210,210,0.3))),

        /* light inner gradient */
        -webkit-gradient(
            linear, 
            left top, 
            right top, 
            color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), 
            color-stop(20%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), 
            color-stop(80%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), 
            color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));        

        -webkit-box-shadow:
            0px -1px #fff, /* top highlight */
            0px 1px 1px #FFFFFF; /* bottom edge */

    -webkit-background-size: 100%, 100%, 100%, 4px 4px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out;

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;

    color: #3A474D;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.2em;

    text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff, 0px -1px #262F33;
}

.button span:hover {
    color: #AEBF3B;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px #97A63A;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover span{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 1px); /* depth of button press */
}
.button:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
        0px 3px rgba(128,128,128,1),
        0px 4px rgba(118,118,118,1),
        0px 5px rgba(108,108,108,1),
        0px 6px rgba(98,98,98,1),
        0px 7px rgba(88,88,88,1),
        0px 8px rgba(78,78,78,1),
        0px 10px 2px 0px rgba(128,128,128,.6); /* shadow */
}
.button:active span{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px); /* depth of button press */
}
```

I can't see what the problem is and or why the to elements dont act the same.. Maybe i'm just to tired to see the obvious but I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the button span from inline-block to:`button span {display: block}`. Then it will fill up the surface, but all buttons will be equal width. If you want variable width, change the button to `button {display: inline-block}` and add a div around each button instead.

You might want some more margin-bottom on the buttons as well.

PS: That code is a bit complicated and unsemantic. You wouldn't have this problem if the styling was applied to a single `<button></button>`.